# Jinja Statement ( {% for loop%}) cannot be read on line server

Tags: html, django

I deployed an ecommerce website on the live server using heroku but having issue with product images as they are not being displayed.
The website is working fine on the local host but causing problem when being deployed online. I inspected the html code and found out that the live website doesn't show the jinja for loop template which is added to the html file. Can anyone please guide me on how to solve this issue?
Here is the link to the website,https://ahad-ecommerce-website.herokuapp.com/ and also the code snippet for the html file

```html
main.html

{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Ecom </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css'%}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var user = '{{request.user}}'
        function getToken(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        var csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');

        function getCookie(name) {
            // Split cookie string and get all individual name=value pairs in an array
            var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");
            // Loop through the array elements
            for(var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
                var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");
                /* Removing whitespace at the beginning of the cookie name
                and compare it with the given string */
                if(name == cookiePair[0].trim()) {
                    // Decode the cookie value and return
                    return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
                }
            }
            // Return null if not found
            return null;
        }
        var cart = JSON.parse(getCookie('cart'))
        if(cart == undefined){
            cart = {}
            console.log('Cookie was created')
            document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"
        }
        console.log('Cart:', cart)

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'store' %}">Ecom</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Store <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <a href="#"class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
            <a href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                <img  id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart.jpg' %}">
            </a>
            <p id="cart-total">{{cartItems}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
 
        {% endblock content%}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>



    {% extends 'store/main.html' %}
    {% load static %}

    {% block content %}
        <div class="row">
            {% for product in products %}
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}">
                <div class="box-element product">
                    <h6><strong> {{product.name}} </strong></h6>
                    <hr>
                    <button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to cart</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#"> View </a>
                    <h4 style="display: inline-block;float: right"><strong> ${{product.price|floatformat:2}} </strong></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Thanks